# Steps to follow when trying to OO design an problem statement

Tags: design-patterns, oop

What are the steps that you follow when approaching a problem statement, which needs to be converted in to a OO design. I do know the approach might be subjective depending on the problem and varying for each but I am sure there must be some basic generic steps that each good designer will follow while breaking down a problem statement in to objects and classes and further to a much concrete design.
Just trying to put up lets say a procedure to follow for new bee designer wannabe's like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest following steps.
1. Write use case. It will help you to understand problem, it should contain basic execution flow (correct path) and alternate paths.
2. Do linguistic analysis and find out class and methods. (This is optional if you know any other good method then use it.)
3. Use SOLID principal for designing your classes.
4. Keep encapsulation, inheritance, polymorphism in mind. If you can't remember them write it on paper or stick it on your desk.
5. One more thing you should keep in mind "What varies encapsulate it".
6. Use design patterns when they are required. Don't enforce design pattern to your code. Try to map your design problem to any design pattern.

I would also suggest "Head First OOAD" book. It is very good book for leaning OOAD.

Comment: Thats a nice list, for an start.That is the kind of answer i was seeking. Just started off with Head First OOAD & Head First Design Patterns and finding it very uself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the free online book http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0131489062/ch01 . It introduces some architectural concepts as well as UML. UML is a diagram tool to map out a design, and is really useful especially for planning large designs before sitting down and coding them.

Answer (score 1):

One of the important steps during a OO design would be the "Single Responsibility Principle". Which is pretty much major basis towards a good design. A http component in your design would do http communication to retrieve jobs but would definitely avoid processing these jobs. The Jobs processor must be independent. Both these (http and job processor) have their single responsibility assigned to them. This is more a general view and inside your components you would create further classes that follow this principle as well.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have been happy with this answer when I was starting out but... it takes a lot of study and practice before it becomes second nature. The best advice I can give is to study designs from people you respect, read some good books (GOF design patterns is a good place to start), and ask experienced people to pick apart your designs.

Learn about things like the single responsibility priciple but you will also need to get a feel for "what is the right size" vs. over-engineering something. That will ultimately depend on the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

while reading the problem, keep a list of the nouns as they might become classes and verbs might become methods.
afterwards, go through them again and validate.

you must read books on design patterns (Head First Design Patterns is very good.) as they will give you a really good insight into how to design better.

don't forget to read on Architectural patterns too.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding requirement in broader perspective is very important to design something which survive for long time. Understanding domain,business,user needs, clients expectations, identifying untold details also matters a lot in designing software. There may be N number of things which affects design, such as frequency of use, time of use, complexity of work flow,priority of users,constraints of system,resources, developer skills ,time, budget and many more. You should be able to visualise bigger picture of problem to solve or requirement.
 This analysis should result in identifying what is constant in system and what may vary in future.Design should abstract the part which may change.New requirement shall not result in to redesign. Divide and rule is the formulas to simplify complexity. Design dedicated, specific packages or modules. Define relations between them.Identify important use cases and try to visualise how your design will handle or satisfy use cases. Make detail design with classes, types ,interfaces. Follow suitable design patterns as per need. Do not forget SOLID principals. Testability , Extensibility,Maintainability , Complexity are things which need to be taken in to consideration at the beginning. You need something more than skill. Thus some people consider it as a art. No design can be  perfect. Do mistakes, learn from them,do not repeat. Thats how it is for me. My answer may not be precise to the question in consideration but hopefully will be helpful.